# Flutter error: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, and I've got an error everytime I run the application:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building DataList(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<List<Store>>], state: _DataListState#67e37):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  DataList
```

Here is my DataList file:

```
class DataList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataListState createState() => _DataListState();
}

class _DataListState extends State<DataList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stores = Provider.of<List<Store>>(context);

    // stores.forEach((d) {
    //   print(d.name);
    // });

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: stores.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return StoreTile(store: stores[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This happens after I login and display a list of stores.
I've printed `stores.length` and it returns 6, but for whatever reason the app finds a `null` and throws an error.

Note that the screen on the app is displayed correctly, but in the Debug Console I get this error.

Any help is appreciated
Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your provider takes a little time to fetch the Store List so the `stores` is null for a while. You can display a progress indicator while the `stores` is null then display the data afterwards

```dart
class _DataListState extends State<DataList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stores = Provider.of<List<Store>>(context);

    // stores.forEach((d) {
    //   print(d.name);
    // });

    return stores == null 
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView.builder(
      itemCount: stores.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return StoreTile(store: stores[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your provider is getting some time to fetch the data, use `CircularProgressIndicator` till then

```
 stores.length >0 ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: stores.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return StoreTile(store: stores[index]);
        },
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
```